# Draw 3 curves together in the same graph and scale

Tags: r, plot

I need to draw three curves together in the same graph with the same scale. I know how to draw two curves together, as the following code:

```
r=0.8
z=2
k=seq(0,5,by=0.1)
y1=(z^2+k*r)/(r*z+k)
y2=z*(z+k*r)/(r+k)
plot(k,y1,type='l',ylab=' ',col="red",ylim=range(c(y1,y2)))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(k,y2,type='l',col="green",ylim=range(c(y1,y2)))
```

It works fine, but I don't know how to add the third curve, means how to set ylim.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: y3=(k^2*z*2-1+sqrt((k^2*z*2)^2+4*k^2*r*2*z*2))

Answer (score 0):

Use `lines`

```
r=0.8
z=2
k=seq(0,5,by=0.1)
y1=(z^2+k*r)/(r*z+k)
y2=z*(z+k*r)/(r+k)
y3=0.8*y2
ymin=min(c(y1,y2,y3))
ymax=max(c(y1,y2,y3))
plot(k,y1,type='l',ylab='lines',col="red",ylim=c(ymin,ymax))
par(new=TRUE)
lines(k,y2,type='l',col="green",ylim=range(c(y1,y2)))
lines(k,y3)
```

[image]

Here is another example, with data you have provided as a comment

```
r=0.8
z=3
p=seq(0.1,5,by=0.1)
y1=(p*z^2+r*z)/(p*r*z+1)
y2=z*(p+r)/(p*r+1)
y3=(p^2*z*2-1+sqrt((p^2*z*2)^2+4*p^2*r*2*z*2))/(2*p*2*r*z)
ymin=-1
ymax=max(c(y1,y2,y3))
plot(p,y1,type='l',ylab='lines',col="red",ylim=c(ymin,ymax))
par(new=TRUE)
lines(p,y2,type='l',col="green",ylim=range(c(y1,y2)))
lines(p,y3, col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Andra,Thank you very much. but sometimes for different function, it will use different scale, say: y3=(k^2*z*2-1+sqrt((k^2*z*2)^2+4*k^2*r*2*z*2))/(2*k*2*r*z) par(new=TRUE) plot(k,y3,type='l',col="blue",ylab='b_R vs b_N')

Comment: Andre,Thanks. I use the following code, R still uses different scales.

Comment: r=0.8 z=3 p=seq(0.1,5,by=0.1) y1=(p*z^2+r*z)/(p*r*z+1) y2=z*(p+r)/(p*r+1) plot(p,y1,type='l',ylab=' ',col="red",ylim=range(c(y1,y2))) par(new=TRUE) plot(p,y2,type='l',col="green",ylab='b_R vs b_N',ylim=range(c(y1,y2))) y3=(p^2*z*2-1+sqrt((p^2*z*2)^2+4*p^2*r*2*z*2))/(2*p*2*r*z) par(new=TRUE) plot(p,y3,type='l',col="blue",ylab='b_R vs b_N',ylim=range(c(-1,6))) As I know for two graphs, I need to use ylim=range(c(y1,y2)) to force R to use the same scale. For the third graph, do I need to use this? and how to use it?

Shaoji